# Confusion URLs include_once in PHP

Tags: php

I know this isn't the right way to use stackoverflow, but i just have to have a quick answer to my problem

this is the folder hierarchy

```
login (folder)
  -- login.php
php (folder)
  -- connection.php

index.php
```

in login.php i use `include_once("../php/connection.php")`

in index.php i use `include_once("login/login.php")`

when i run index.php i get the following issues

Warning: include_once(../php/connection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /.../public_html/plog/login/login.php on line 3

thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: Why not use root-relative link?

Comment: @Thamilan because this is just a subfolder and i might want to add it to another website without having to change anything

Comment: Define base URL with PHP define('BASE_URL', 'your subdirectory');

Comment: @Thamilan can you show me an example about that?

Comment: Define base URL with PHP `define('BASE_URL', 'your URL with subdirectory');` Define it once and then change it later when you move your website

Comment: @Thamilan and how do i gain access to it later
i don't know really much about PHP functions. Just read this
http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php. Do you think this is the right idea to do it? In which file should i define what you said? Will it work if i put it in `index.php`

Comment: Yes it should..

Comment: @Thamilan ok i'll try to make this. but once t is defined can i call it frem anywhere? or do i have to import the index.php file then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and found that the best way to do this, without having to declare any constants was the following:

in login.php i include connection.php this way `include_once( substr(__DIR__, 0, strrpos(__DIR__, "/") + 1 ) . "php/connection.php")`;

so this would fix the entire problem. I don't have to define anything. Now i can copy this subfolder almost everywhere without having to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

You are closer to the best answer, but a better pattern is this:

You create a bootstrap script and place it in a known location.  For this to work all that is important is that every script needs to require_once() the bootstrap file relative to that script.

Most frameworks use a front controller pattern which is a typical entrypoint to MVC frameworks, but even if that is too complex for you at this point, this technique still works so long as you always require_once('../somedir/bootstrap.php');

The bootstrap.php script is a good place for any configuration settings, reading environment variables, setting constants etc.

Prominently at the start you want to have something like this:

```
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
}
```

So now, all that is important is that you understand the relationship any other files may have to the directory that bootstrap.php is in.  Let's say for example, you put it in the login.php directory.

Then your require_once() would be:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . login.php);
```

For connection it would be:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . '../php/connection.php');
```

I highly recommend require_once over include_once, if your system is effectively non-functional without the included file, as it probably would be if you can't connect to the database on login.  require_once will cause a runtime error, whereas include_once just continues on it's merry way whether or not it could actually find and include the file.

Not a huge fan of your directory naming to be honest.  A directory called /php?  What does that tell you?  Isn't this all php code?

People have put a lot of thought into good structures, and then there is the PSR efforts, composer etc.  Take [a look at this](https://github.com/php-pds/skeleton) for a better plan.

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you so much for your help. That is the coolest and most detailed answer i have received so far from anybody. Great for learning purposes. :-)

Comment: Glad to have helped.  Check out the composer tool and http://www.php-fig.org/psr/, at least the 1st 2 PSR's.  Should really jump start your thinking and facilitate an entry point into use of component libraries.  The symfony components are a great starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I update the code so with the constant BASE_URL you will define the root so you can use it from other site

```
<?php
 define('BASE_URL', 'http://example.com');
 include(BASE_URL."/php/connection.php");
?>
```

Comment: I am not looking for a root-relative link cuz i might wanna get the subfolder (/blog) and put it in another website and change the name of the subfolder (/blog1121) without having to change anything that it contains inside

Comment: do i have to include the file when i do the `define('BASE_URL', 'http://example.com');` ?

Comment: no because you may include more file and folder while your project expand so just define the base